# VS2019 Find enters endless loop

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2019

I try to find a certain string in my xaml and cs files.

So I press cntrl-F and get this pop-up in the right top, enter  the string and send it on its way through all the project files.

When it needs to switch from .cs file to .xaml files, the find pop=up changes to a "stand-alone" popup and starts looping endlessly, while flashing the string wildly in the entry field.

I can only abort VS via the task manager. No clicking on VS will stop it.
What is going on here?

Never did that in VS2017...

But maybe it's an error in the code on my part. I dunno...

Any suggestions?

btw: does this in another project of mine too, which I did not touch for months....

Comment: If it's the find within VS, I wouldn't think it has anything to do with any errors in your code itself.

Comment: Sounds like a 2019 problem. Have you tried re-installing/repairing the install? I can't say that'll help... but I've never seen it loop infinitely. Could you post a screenshot of what you're trying to search? Even if your project was massive and you had some elaborate regex in the search, I wouldn't think it would lock up indefinitely.

Comment: It's not a very large project. I search for variable names, function names etc.Things that occur in .cs AND in .xaml, obviously. No regexpr. plain old "find". And as soon as it's going to .xaml.... Bang!
I update VS regularly.

Comment: Re-installed.First it seemed to be a solution, but now it does not: same old thing....

Answer (score 0):

i experienced very similar problems with the find functionality (i.e. going into an infinite loop) when searching .aspx, .ashx and .master files within an ASP.NET project using Visual Studio 2019 16.2.4 (which is the latest version)

the links below report the same issue with .resx files:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/669236/infinite-loop-during-search-ctrlf-on-a-resx-string.html

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/664130/search-error-resource-string-designer.html?inRegister=true

I would suggest therefore this is a general problem with the text search functionality within VS 2019 itself which affects certain environments and certain files

As per the links above Microsoft have acknowledged the issue however the only fix available is to install the "preview" (16.3) version: in my own case this resolved the issue

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview